# Is it possible to use Custom label with Options attribute in Aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

I'm trying to replace hard-coded emails with custom labels in the Aura component and am getting the below error message.

*failed to save psa_selectfromadd.cmp: cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}: source*

**SelectFromAdd.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction" description="My Lightning Component">
    <lightning:quickActionAPI aura:id="quickActionAPI" />
    
    <aura:attribute type="string" name="email1" default="{!$Label.c.pscinfo_psc}" />
    <aura:attribute type="string" name="email2" default="{!$Label.c.ggsinfo_psc}" />

    <aura:attribute type="String[]" name="values" default="[]" access="private" />
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
        {'label': 'pscinfo@psc.com', 'value': '{!v.email1}'},
        {'label': 'ggsinfo@psc.com', 'value': '{!v.email2}'}]"/>

    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" />

    <div>
        <lightning:radioGroup name="radioGroup"
                              label="Select From Email Address:"
                              options="{!v.options}"
                              value="{!v.values}"
                              type="radio"
                              onchange="{!c.handleChange}"
                              required="true"/>
    </div>
</aura: component>
```

**SelectFromAddController.js**

```
({
    handleChange: function(cmp, event) {
        var changeValue = event.getParam("value");
        var actionAPI = cmp.find("quickActionAPI");
        var fields = {
            FromAddress: {
                value: changeValue
            }
        };
        var args = {
            actionName: "Case.PSA_Send_Email",
            entityName: "Case",
            targetFields: fields,
            submitOnSuccess: false
        };
        actionAPI.setActionFieldValues(args)
            .then(function() {
                // actionAPI.invokeAction(args);
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.error(e.errors);
            });
    },
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var options = [
            $A.get("$Label.c.pscinfo_psc"),
            $A.get("$Label.c.ggsinfo_psc")
        ];
        component.set('v.options', options);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [datasource design attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm) for your aura attribute. It allows an [Apex class to be used as the source of the options](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm#components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists).

In the apex class you can return the custom labels, whether dynamically fetched emails, for example from [custom metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5) or [custom settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm).

**Example with the custom metadata, it allows not to hardcode everything and not create custom labels.**

**Apex class**

```
public class CustomMetadataEmailPicklist implements VisualEditor.DynamicPickList {
    
    public class PicklistOption {
        public String label;
        public String value;
        
        public PicklistOption(String label, String value) {
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    
    public List<VisualEditor.PicklistRow> getValues() {
        List<VisualEditor.PicklistRow> picklistRows = new List<VisualEditor.PicklistRow>();
        
        // Retrieve custom metadata records containing email addresses
        List<Custom_Metadata__mdt> emailRecords = Custom_Metadata__mdt.getAll().values();
        
        for (Custom_Metadata__mdt record : emailRecords) {
            String email = record.Email__c;
            picklistRows.add(new PicklistOption(email, email));
        }
        
        return picklistRows;
    }
}
```

**Aura component**

```
<design:component>
        <design:attribute name="options" datasource="apex://CustomMetadataEmailPicklist "/>
</design:component>
```